# Как отсортировать по столбцу связи многие ко многим?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, order-by

Как можно использовать orderBy для сортировки по столбцу из связи belongsToMany()?

```
  $result = Food::query()->whereHas("type", function($query){
       $query->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
  })->get(); //ничего не сортирует

  или

  $result = Food::query()->with(["type", function($query){
       $query->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
  }])->get(); //ничего не сортирует
```

Вариант с join не подходит и сортировка коллекции тоже

Comment: Покажи структуру связанных таблиц и мидели

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = Food::query()->whereHas("type", function($query){
   return $query->orderBy('created_at','DESC');})->get();
```

Может `return` поможет?)

Comment: нет, не поможет)

Comment: @Aleks ну тогда это уже нужно прямо в код смотреть... Тут вроде все норм)